# What does this PHP syntax mean?

Tags: php, syntax

Consider the code:

```
$a = "foobar";
echo $a{3}; // prints b
```

I know `$a[3]` is `'b'` but how come using `{}` in place of `[]` produec the same result ?

Comment: FYI, arrays can also be accessed with `{}` instead of `[]`. Once upon a time, `[]` was recommended for arrays and `{}` for string. Now, `[]` is the recommended way to go.

Answer (score 10):

You can read [here in official documentation](http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.string.php) about braces:

> String s may also be accessed using
>   braces, as in $str{42}, for the same
>   purpose. However, this syntax is
>   deprecated as of PHP 5.3.0. Use square
>   brackets instead, such as $str[42].

Answer (score 6):

**EDIT** This thread may interest you: ["dropping curly braces"](http://www.mail-archive.com/internals@lists.php.net/msg18647.html)

It's just an alternative syntax; the two forms compile to exactly the same bytecode:

```
<?php
$str = "aaab";
echo $str{3}; 
echo $str[3];
```

```
number of ops:  9
compiled vars:  !0 = $str
line     # *  op                           fetch          ext  return  operands
---------------------------------------------------------------------------------
   2     0  >   EXT_STMT                                                 
         1      ASSIGN                                                   !0, 'aaab'
   3     2      EXT_STMT                                                 
         3      FETCH_DIM_R                                      $1      !0, 3
         4      ECHO                                                     $1
   4     5      EXT_STMT                                                 
         6      FETCH_DIM_R                                      $2      !0, 3
         7      ECHO                                                     $2
         8    > RETURN                                                   1
```

Comment: wow. can you please give a name of program that shows this table?

Answer (score 5):

It's the same, but the `{}` syntax is deprecated as of PHP 5.3.

Answer (score 0):

{} and [] are the same. it is your choice what to use. [] is more common though.

Comment: {} is deprecated, and shouldn't be used